# Trying to use extra space on a dynamically allocated VM

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive, gparted

So I am currently working with a ubuntu VM on a windows host. And originally set up the VM to 50GB with a 20GB ram leaving 30GB for hard disk memory. I've since filled that up and have modified the maximum to be 80GB using VBox Manage modify hd.

However if I try to download a 3GB file I get the error that I don't have enough space. I run df -h and get this as output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBnzX.jpg

I open up the Gparted partitioner to see this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjDKr.jpg

The question is, how can I allocate those 30GB to sda1 such that I can work and generate files in my root directory without running out of space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's a fairly normal problem to run into. What I would do is temporarily delete the swap partition and "extended partition". Then gparted can use the un-allocated space to add to the first partition.

First, close whatever it is you have running that needs 20gb swap space. (I'm curious as to what that is)

Then, you have to turn swap off:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

(Yes, gparted has a "swapoff" feature, but I've never trusted it, could just be me)

Once swap is off, start gparted and delete the swap partition and "extended partition". When those are deleted, you can right click on /dev/sda1 and select "resize/move". Take up all but the space you need for swap, then create a new partition for swap, and once created right click and select "Format to" and select linux-swap. No need for the "extended partition" part of the process.

Once there, you need to turn swap back on. On my test system, "swapon -a" didn't work, so:

```
sudo swapon /dev/sda2
```

Hope this helps!